# link to a new jsp page inside WEB-INF

Tags: java, jsp

I want to link to a jsp page that is in the WEB-INF directory so I wrote the below code inside my jsp

```
<a href="/WEB-INF/searchCDInfo.jsp" >Search CD</a>
```

but the web server cannot find the page! what can I do?

Comment: Please provide web.xml file

Comment: can you please explain how can I link to another jsp page inside a jsp page in web.xml ??

Comment: If your page url is: localhost:8080/ProjectName/index.html so the link should be /ProjectName/searchCDInfo.jsp

Comment: but please learn harder about JSP, I guess your JSP skill does not good at all

Comment: You can't.  Resources under WEB-INF are not publicly accessible. You can write a servlet and have that forward to the JSP. https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=vMGRWxa9eq8C&pg=PA615&lpg=PA615&dq=web-inf+protected&source=bl&ots=SYbon55j8V&sig=qPqaO7XmrGCJiaX6z0v3kmgTgx4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEUQ6AEwBWoVChMI0NT7tsiKyQIVx9YUCh2PoQP4#v=onepage&q=web-inf%20protected&f=false

Comment: the fact is that my jsp page is in WEB-INF folder, so we cannot link to it with the <a> tag! I am looking for the correct way for doing that...

Comment: You need to write a Servlet that will forward to the jsp in its doGet() or doPost() method. http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips-100042/48-javaserver-pages/1883-how-to-forward-requests-from-servlet-to-jsp.html

Comment: WEB-INF is supposed to be used as a private directory,you can't have public links to pointing to it's contents

Comment: Are you sure? I am testing, using direct link as I said and it works as expected: my page display.